# Add an object with a default label at the beginning of a select list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an array

```
const response = [
  {
    _id: "6447a35a2b179e0727f894f9",
    __v: 0,
    id: "672850c9-88a1-4649-baa4-def3d67f67bd",
    key: "Boing 777",
    model: "Boing 777",
    variant: null,
    capacity: 200,
    galleys: [
      {
        id: "A1-Alpha-20",
        name: "A1-Alpha-20",
        carts: [
          {
            quantity: 5,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Full Cart",
            id: "full",
          },
          {
            quantity: 4,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Half Cart",
            id: "half",
          },
          {
            quantity: 2,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "SMU",
            id: "smu",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "C3-Charlie-90",
        id: "C3-Charlie-90",
        carts: [
          {
            id: "full",
            name: "Full Cart",
            weight: 0,
            volume: 0,
            dimensions: {
              length: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            quantity: 6,
          },
          {
            id: "half",
            name: "Half Cart",
            weight: 0,
            volume: 0,
            dimensions: {
              length: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            quantity: 3,
          },
          {
            id: "smu",
            name: "SMU",
            weight: 0,
            volume: 0,
            dimensions: {
              length: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: "D1-Delta-60",
        name: "D1-Delta-60",
        carts: [
          {
            quantity: 5,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Full Cart",
            id: "full",
          },
          {
            quantity: 6,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Half Cart",
            id: "half",
          },
          {
            quantity: 3,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "SMU",
            id: "smu",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    layout: [
      {
        seatLocation: "window",
        seatNumber: "1A",
        seatIndex: 1,
        colId: "A",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 1,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1B",
        seatIndex: 2,
        colId: "B",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 2,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1C",
        seatIndex: 3,
        colId: "C",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 3,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "aisle",
        seatNumber: "1D",
        seatIndex: 4,
        colId: "D",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 4,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "aisle",
        seatNumber: "1E",
        seatIndex: 5,
        colId: "E",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 5,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1F",
        seatIndex: 6,
        colId: "F",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 6,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1G",
        seatIndex: 7,
        colId: "G",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 7,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "window",
        seatNumber: "1H",
        seatIndex: 8,
        colId: "H",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 8,
        row: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: "6447abeb2b179e0727f894fa",
    __v: 0,
    id: "7fd5621c-3026-4e03-a263-bdd4faf30787",
    key: "A350-Long Haul",
    model: "A350",
    variant: "Long Haul",
    capacity: 60,
    galleys: [
      {
        name: "G75-98",
        id: "G75-98",
        carts: [
          {
            quantity: 3,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Full Cart",
            id: "full",
          },
          {
            quantity: 5,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Half Cart",
            id: "half",
          },
          {
            quantity: 1,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "SMU",
            id: "smu",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    layout: [],
  },
  {
    _id: "6448d7302b179e0727f8952d",
    __v: 0,
    id: "b1389585-1f3b-4e6b-9931-03e185e73344",
    key: "Bell boeing-short haul",
    model: "Bell boeing",
    variant: "short haul",
    capacity: 55,
    galleys: [],
    layout: [],
  },
  {
    _id: "6448dad62b179e0727f8952e",
    __v: 0,
    id: "8743ebb3-ffea-4919-b711-4cb40da653db",
    key: "Boeing 756-long haul",
    model: "Boeing 756",
    variant: "long haul",
    capacity: 60,
    galleys: [
      {
        name: "G54",
        id: "G54",
        carts: [
          {
            quantity: 3,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Full Cart",
            id: "full",
          },
          {
            quantity: 4,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Half Cart",
            id: "half",
          },
          {
            quantity: 4,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "SMU",
            id: "smu",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    layout: [],
  },
  {
    _id: "6448df442b179e0727f8952f",
    __v: 0,
    id: "ed59eee2-2b35-42fa-a7ab-72cf723c8fa7",
    key: "airbus380-short haul",
    model: "airbus380",
    variant: "short haul",
    capacity: 65,
    galleys: [],
    layout: [],
  },
  {
    _id: "644a1edd2b179e0727f89530",
    __v: 0,
    id: "0a288a23-f660-46e4-9d95-e9b9f4f95411",
    key: "Air 350-business class",
    model: "Air 350",
    variant: "business class",
    capacity: 60,
    galleys: [
      {
        name: "G50-Back-30",
        id: "G50-Back-30",
        carts: [
          {
            quantity: 5,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Full Cart",
            id: "full",
          },
          {
            quantity: 3,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Half Cart",
            id: "half",
          },
          {
            quantity: 2,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "SMU",
            id: "smu",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: "G60-Front-20",
        name: "G60-Front-20",
        carts: [
          {
            id: "full",
            name: "Full Cart",
            weight: 0,
            volume: 0,
            dimensions: {
              length: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            quantity: 4,
          },
          {
            id: "half",
            name: "Half Cart",
            weight: 0,
            volume: 0,
            dimensions: {
              length: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            quantity: 2,
          },
          {
            id: "smu",
            name: "SMU",
            weight: 0,
            volume: 0,
            dimensions: {
              length: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    layout: [],
  },
  {
    _id: "644a1ee42b179e0727f89531",
    __v: 0,
    id: "0c585950-1991-44bd-8298-2e93e88925e3",
    key: "Air 350-business class",
    model: "Air 350",
    variant: "business class",
    capacity: 60,
    galleys: [
      {
        name: "G90",
        id: "G90",
        carts: [
          {
            quantity: 2,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Full Cart",
            id: "full",
          },
          {
            quantity: 2,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "Half Cart",
            id: "half",
          },
          {
            quantity: 4,
            dimensions: {
              height: 0,
              breadth: 0,
              length: 0,
            },
            volume: 0,
            weight: 0,
            name: "SMU",
            id: "smu",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    layout: [
      {
        seatLocation: "window",
        seatNumber: "1A",
        seatIndex: 1,
        colId: "A",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 1,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1B",
        seatIndex: 2,
        colId: "B",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 2,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1C",
        seatIndex: 3,
        colId: "C",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 3,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "aisle",
        seatNumber: "1D",
        seatIndex: 4,
        colId: "D",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 4,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "aisle",
        seatNumber: "1E",
        seatIndex: 5,
        colId: "E",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 5,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1F",
        seatIndex: 6,
        colId: "F",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 6,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "middle",
        seatNumber: "1G",
        seatIndex: 7,
        colId: "G",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 7,
        row: 1,
      },
      {
        seatLocation: "window",
        seatNumber: "1H",
        seatIndex: 8,
        colId: "H",
        rowId: "1",
        col: 8,
        row: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need to create three select lists the first should have all the model values from the response the second variant and the third the galley name which is inside the galleys array.
I was able to make an array object with key label and value fields.I am trying to get a default object in each select list which has a label select model, select variant and select galley.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (response) {
    const actModel = [{ key: 0, label: "select Aircraft", value: "" }];
    const actModelArr = resposnse.map((act, index) => {
      return actModel.push({ key: index, label: act.model, value: "" });
    });
    const actVr = response.map((actVr, index) => {
      return { key: index, label: actVr.variant, value: "" };
    });
    const galleyNames = response.map((gl) =>
      gl.galleys.map((cr, index) => {
        return { key: index, label: cr.name, value: "" };
      })
    )[0];
    setAircraftOptions({
      model: actModelArr,
      variant: actVr,
      galley: galleyNames,
    });
  }
}, [response]);
```

I tried to push an array in const `actModel` so as to get the select model in the first item of  the list is there a way to do this for all the three lists

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that, reducing the Array with a default option:

```
const actModelArr = response.reduce(
    (acc, item, index) => [
        ...acc,
        { key: index + 1, label: item.model, value: "" },
    ],
    [{ key: 0, label: "select Aircraft", value: "" }]
);
// [{"key":0,"label":"select Aircraft","value":""},{"key":1,"label":"Boing 777","value":""},{"key":2,"label":"A350","value":""},{"key":3,"label":"Bell boeing","value":""},{"key":4,"label":"Boeing 756","value":""},{"key":5,"label":"airbus380","value":""},{"key":6,"label":"Air 350","value":""},{"key":7,"label":"Air 350","value":""}]

const actVr = response.reduce(
    (acc, item, index) => [
        ...acc,
        {
        key: index + 1,
        label: item.variant,
        value: "",
        },
    ],
    [{ key: 0, label: "select variant", value: "" }]
);
// '[{"key":0,"label":"select variant","value":""},{"key":1,"label":null,"value":""},{"key":2,"label":"Long Haul","value":""},{"key":3,"label":"short haul","value":""},{"key":4,"label":"long haul","value":""},{"key":5,"label":"short haul","value":""},{"key":6,"label":"business class","value":""},{"key":7,"label":"business class","value":""}]'

const galleyNames = response.reduce(
    (acc, item) => [
        ...acc,
        item.galleys.map((item, index) => ({
        key: index + 1,
        label: item.name,
        value: "",
        })),
    ],
    [{ key: 0, label: "select galley", value: "" }]
);
// [{"key":0,"label":"select galley","value":""},[{"key":1,"label":"A1-Alpha-20","value":""},{"key":2,"label":"C3-Charlie-90","value":""},{"key":3,"label":"D1-Delta-60","value":""}],[{"key":1,"label":"G75-98","value":""}],[],[{"key":1,"label":"G54","value":""}],[],[{"key":1,"label":"G50-Back-30","value":""},{"key":2,"label":"G60-Front-20","value":""}],[{"key":1,"label":"G90","value":""}]]

setAircraftOptions({ model: actModelArr, variant: actVr, galley: galleyNames });
// {"model":[{"key":0,"label":"select Aircraft","value":""},{"key":1,"label":"Boing 777","value":""},{"key":2,"label":"A350","value":""},{"key":3,"label":"Bell boeing","value":""},{"key":4,"label":"Boeing 756","value":""},{"key":5,"label":"airbus380","value":""},{"key":6,"label":"Air 350","value":""},{"key":7,"label":"Air 350","value":""}],"variant":[{"key":0,"label":"select variant","value":""},{"key":1,"label":null,"value":""},{"key":2,"label":"Long Haul","value":""},{"key":3,"label":"short haul","value":""},{"key":4,"label":"long haul","value":""},{"key":5,"label":"short haul","value":""},{"key":6,"label":"business class","value":""},{"key":7,"label":"business class","value":""}],"galley":[{"key":0,"label":"select galley","value":""},[{"key":1,"label":"A1-Alpha-20","value":""},{"key":2,"label":"C3-Charlie-90","value":""},{"key":3,"label":"D1-Delta-60","value":""}],[{"key":1,"label":"G75-98","value":""}],[],[{"key":1,"label":"G54","value":""}],[],[{"key":1,"label":"G50-Back-30","value":""},{"key":2,"label":"G60-Front-20","value":""}],[{"key":1,"label":"G90","value":""}]]}
```